# Dynamically insert a frame inside a frameset as first frame in native javascript?

Tags: javascript, frame, frameset

```
var m = document.getElementById('mainframeset');
m.appendChild(newFrame);
```

inserts a frame inside a frameset as last frame.

**What I want here is to insert the frame as the first frame.**
Something like this :

```
frameSet[0].insertBefore(newframe, frameSet[0].document.frames[0]);
```

It doesn't work,though.

Thaks

Comment: `frameSet[0].insertBefore(newframe, frameSet[0].firstChild);` does not help?

Comment: Hi, Great....it worked it worked it worked.....hohohoho... Post this as answer so that I could accept it.I knocked myself out searching for it.Thanks a lot man.Any book suggestion for javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
frameSet[0].insertBefore(newframe, frameSet[0].firstChild);
```